# can't implement CSRF in Spring 4

Tags: spring-security, csrf

I have CSRF enabled in xml file for Spring 4:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <csrf />
</http>
```

And added it to logining form:

```
<form name='form' action="<c:url value='/login' />"  method='post'>

          <table>  
           <tr>  
            <td>User:</td>  
            <td><input type='text' style="width:100%" name='username' value=''>
            </td>  
           </tr>  
           <tr>  
            <td>Password:</td>  
            <td><input type='password' style="width:100%" name='password' />  
            </td>  
           </tr>  
           <tr>  
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit"  type="submit" value="TryMe)" />
            </td>  
           </tr>  
           <tr>  
            <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />  
            </td>  
           </tr>
          </table>
            <input type="text" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

But still when I try to access resource and get redirected to logining page I get error:

```
Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?
```

What I have missed?

**EDIT:**
I have spotted that CSRF does work with default login page!

Comment: I hope you added the Spring-security jsp tag, ` <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>`

Comment: No. But I do not use it on my page.

Comment: Please add it in your JSP and for the resources you have to disable security. This should solve your problem. Let me know if it does.

Comment: But I do not want to disable anything. I just want to activate CSRF. I dont understand why I need sec tag(((

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with login-page name. My name was "logining", but Spring Security didnt add CSRF tag to it(( Dont know no why. But if I put "/login" with my login page after redirect - everything works. This tutorial helped me a lot:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-logout